# To-do app for Mac OS X

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to organize my to do's for programming an iphone app. I found [this](http://www.mytinytodo.net/), and I really like it, but is not native to Mac OS X. Is there any app similar to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the great [wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/) which is free, provides collaboration and a companion iPhone app (also free). Does what it's made for. Customizable and sexy :)
(No I don't work at 6wunderkinder!)

Comment: I used Wunderlist but now I don't see it cool anymore, at all. They software is wrote using Titanium framework and after *3* months from the initial reporting they still not support OS X 10.7 Lion. With such support behind I would prefer to look for other solutions.

Comment: And customization only to the various backgrounds you can choose, which doesn't actually help you get your tasks done. Buggy, and doesn't act right on the Mac (or iPhone for that matter).

Comment: While I never encountered bugs, it's true that the  application didn't evolve much since I posted the answer above, and customization is quite limited.

Answer (score 6):

[Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/iphone/) (39$) is best to-do application i've ever used. It's a simple application with powerful features.

My favorite feature is synchronizing between mac/ipad/iphone. One disadvantage that it is paid application.

Comment: things has toooo much featrures..it's not simple anymore. Wunderlist is really simple and VERY powerful.

Answer (score 4):

iCal that ships with OS X has a ToDo List feature that works well.

You'll need to be more specific about which features of MyTinyToDo you like, if you are wanting better recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

I use [ToodleDo](http://www.toodledo.com/) for all of my To Do lists. It's a website so it is accessible anywhere (I use it as the default page in my browser on my laptop) and they have a native iPhone app that does a great job syncing. It's not Mac-native, but it is very agreeable to Mac users and you can export your lists as iCal calendars if you so choose. You get a lot of functionality for being free, but it does pay to subscribe if you have long-term uses for it.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, but you could run MyTinyToDo locally in apache and put it in a widget and put it on your dashboard.  Or use [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) to float it on your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of good apps for what you'd like to plan. My suggestions are:

[Omnifocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus_for_iphone/) for iPhone (it's one of the most expensive on the market but the features are excellent)

-[Todo](http://www.appigo.com/todo) a simple but convenient Todo app, really similar to the one you mentionned and easy to handle, with a cloud sync service for tasks

[2Do](http://2doapp.com/en/2Do/features.html) the one that I can't live without (no joke!), probably the most complete planner app on iPhone.

Hope this will help you make your mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want "native", Why not simply use Mail? It has a "notes" section and it'll sync w/ any ios device out there... Make a new note & at the top type in "To do" & go for it, doesn't get much more "native" than that.